# Having problems with authorization when sending emails using PHPMailer even though Gmail app password is given

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm writing a program to send email in PHP and I'm having a problem with the error 'Could not authenticate' even though I've given the app password from Gmail.

```
<?php
    $username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

    require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
    function sendemailforAccount($email, $subject, $body, $attachmentPath = "", $attachmentName = ""){
    global $username;
    global $password;
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = $username;
    $mail->Password   = $password;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', '');
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    if($attachmentPath != "" && $attachmentName != ""){
        $mail->addAttachment($attachmentPath, $attachmentName);
    }
    if($mail->send()){
        return true;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
return false;
}

?>
```

And when I execute the following command it gives the following error
`sendemailforAccount($email, $subject, $content, $attachmentPath, $attachmentName);`

> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H4ML.png)

How should I solve this problem? Thanks everyone

Comment: Change the SMTPDebug mode to 2 and see if you get more details. See also the troubleshooting guide at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting for more tips

Comment: Gmail *really* wants you to use XOAUTH2 these days.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2022, Gmail stopped third party applications from using username and password authentication, hence the error you are getting.

[Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?authuser=1&hl=en&authuser=1&visit_id=637903001689732939-2002583010&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-off-for-your-account%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-on-for-your-account)